# Annoying Blank VBA Window

Tags: excel, vba, window

This started randomly while working on VBA code and now it won't stop popping up everytime I log in while Excel is already open. Even if I'm not working on any of the VBA at the time, if I log off then log back in a blank, empty VBA editor window will be open. It is just annoying, anyone have any idea how to make it stop, or why it started doing this?
I have tried restarting the computer.

Comment: Try un-maximizing the VBA window before saving and closing.

Comment: It seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: I will add it as an answer so this question can be closed.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un-maximize the Visual Basic Editor window prior to saving and closing.

This is a known issue as referenced here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829059